# Wordpress shortcode not working in Retro theme

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using wordpress retro theme, and using a plugin to show hide text `"[wpex Read more]hidden text[/wpex]"` but it is not working, data is displaying by custom function i went there and change the code to `"retun do_shortcode( $result );"` but is working for simple shortcode without parameters, not working with shortcode have partmeters like i mentioned before.
can anyone guide me what to do ?

Thank you very much

Comment: show ur shortcode function

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parameter in shortcode, assign the Read More text to a parameter like this

```
[wpex parameter="Read more"]hidden text[/wpex]
```

Comment: <code>function wpex_process($content) {
 $offset = 0;
 $stag = '[wpex ';
 $etag = '[/wpex]';
 while(stripos($content, $stag, $offset)) {
  // string to replace
  $s = stripos($content, $stag, $offset); 
  $e = stripos($content, $etag, $s) + strlen($etag); 
  // inside data
  $ds = stripos($content, ']', $s) + 1;
  $de = $e - strlen($etag);
  // style tag
  $ss = $s + strlen($stag);
  $se = $ds - 1;
  $sstring = substr($content, $s, $e - $s);
  $sdesc = substr($content, $ss, $se - $ss); 
  $sdata = substr($content, $ds, $de - $ds);
</code>